# JAVAFX, Scenebuilder

Tags: java, javafx

Есть ссылка в десктопном приложении через Scenebuilder сделанное, надо ей присвоить переход, то есть в Scenebuilder есть fx:id -  linkURL, и на setOnAction надо сделать переход на страницу веб-браузера. Помогите, начинающий на Java

```
linkURL.setOnAction(event -> {

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, через такую конструкцию:

```
try {
    Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
    d.browse(new URI("http://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=https://youtube.com"));
} catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Имейте ввиду, что переходы в браузер платформозависимые и код для win, *nix и mac будет различаться, так что стоит добавить хотя бы проверку на ОС

Comment: та мне так, для Windows хотя бы, но спасибо